# Creating an alias for a bitbucket git repository

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

Got a Bitbucket git repository which has out-grown its original scope so that the repo name no longer represent the content.

Can I create an 'alias repository' which will point to the existing one, but with a better name, while keeping the old name working to avoid updating existing checkouts, CI systems, etc.?

I vision here two repo names, but a single repo state which is available under both names.

Comment: How do you see this working? I could see it being a remote. You probably should avoid using “pull”.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and:

- clone the repo
- [rename your current BitBucket repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25511692/6309)
- create a new one, re-using the name of the original repo
- reset your local clone to the right SHA1 (loosing the part of the recent history that does not interest you)
- pushing the local repo to the newly created one.

Comment: I visioned here two repo names, but a single repo state which is available under both names.

Comment: @UriCohen I don't know of two names for *one* repo. I am more familiar with two different repos (since the repo hosting server will know how to avoid duplication of common SHA1s)